# Python3 - loop on xml config file

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, configuration

I want to build config file in xml that have a key value, and I can loop on keys.

For example I have 3 student (id and name)

```
<students>
<student id="ST1" name="Jhone" />
<student id="ST5" name="Pitter" />
<student id="ST77" name="Arik" />
</students>
```

How can I put it on xml config file that in python I can check if I have STxx key and get the value?

Comment: Please share what you did so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

STUDENTS = [('ST1','Jhone'),('ST5','Pitter'),('ST77','Arik')]

def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level*"  "
    j = "\n" + (level-1)*"  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for subelem in elem:
            indent(subelem, level+1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = j
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = j
    return elem 

def find_student_by_id(doc,_id):
  arg = ".//student[@id='{}']".format(_id)
  return doc.findall(arg)

# build the XML document
root = ET.Element('students')
for student in STUDENTS:
    student_element = ET.SubElement(root, 'student')
    student_element.set('name',student[1])
    student_element.set('id',student[0])

# print the xml document
indent(root)
ET.dump(root)

# search the document by id
student = find_student_by_id(root,'ST1')
# found
print(student)
student = find_student_by_id(root,'ST111')
# not found
print(student)
```

Comment: I tried to set in file `<students>
  <student id="ST1" name="Jhone" />
<student id="ST5" name="Pitter" />
<student id="ST77" name="Arik" />
</students>`   and then use your code to find student like   `root = open ('test.txt').read()

# search the document by id
student = find_student_by_id(root,'ST1')` but I got error  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'findall'`

Comment: See here how to load the file into XML doc https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html